# function to change a list of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I want to automate some routine with python code:

```py
portfolio = [ apple, tesla, amazon]

def change_dim(list): 
   for x in list:
      x = x['Adj Close']
   return list
# That doesn't work for me.
```

I have a list of pandas data frame with stock data(5 columns in each) . I need a function that takes as argument that list, goes through all items and change them to dfs with only 'Adj Close' column and then return the list of changes dfs. I would appreciate if you could give more than 1 option.

Add just want to ask here about another issue:
After I have this data frames, I want to merge them:

```
# apple , amazon - two df with the same datetime index and 'Adj Close' #columns
portfolio = pd.merge(apple, amazon, how = 'left', on = apple)
```

that gives me next error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-e47969d90c08> in <module>
----> 1 portfolio = pd.merge(apple, amazon, how = 'left', on = apple)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     45                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     46                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
---> 47                          validate=validate)
     48     return op.get_result()
     49 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    527         (self.left_join_keys,
    528          self.right_join_keys,
--> 529          self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
    530 
    531         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    821                         if rk is not None:
    822                             right_keys.append(
--> 823                                 right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    824                             join_names.append(rk)
    825                         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1704             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1705         else:
-> 1706             raise KeyError(key)
   1707 
   1708         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: Date
```

What is the problem?
Thank you, very much!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, provide your sample input with your output along with your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

```
portfolio = [ apple, tesla, amazon]

def change_dim(list): 
   for x in list:
      x = x['Adj Close']
   return list
```

The problem here is that apple, tesla, and amazon are not defined variables.
You could fix this by defining them like:

```
apple = value
tesla = value
amazon = value

portfolio = [ apple, tesla, amazon]

def change_dim(list): 
   for x in list:
      x = x['Adj Close']
   return list
```

If you need to define it without giving it a value just say variable = None